# Long press gesture on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView image circle. I want to long press the picture zoom in and move it to another place, and when released it declined and remained this place. But when I release the finger, the picture moves to the starting place. Why? Here's the code:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
recognizer.minimumPressDuration = .5;
recognizer.delegate = self;
[circle addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

- (void)move:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   UIView *image_ = sender.view;
   CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:image_.superview];
   if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
           image_.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
       } completion:nil];
   }
   if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
       image_.center = point;
   }
   if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
       image_.center = point;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
           image_.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, 1.f);
       } completion:nil];
   }
}
```

Comment: you need to use UIPanGesture

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it is moving back to the start is because you are using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. This type of recogniser will not give you a reliable update on tracking the user's input location. Once the gesture ends it is probably giving you the point where the gesture was first initiated.

I would also set the image's transform back to the identity transform rather than scale it back to 1.0f in both dimensions.

The solution would be to use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and properly track the gesture's location in the view. This will work far better, and on top of that it is the right way to do it.

Comment: using uiPanGestureRecognizer I can not get a long press, but in the future I need to work scroll gesture and long press

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you is to add Image view to UIView.
So its UIView will be container UIView and add UILongPressGesture to its container view.
Then it will work. UIImageview doesn't reply to UILongPressGesture and its container view will reply about it.
You will get the result what you want.
Hope your success.